# Wont display outcome of heads or tails using API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I tried parsing but it wont display like it did when my professor did it even though I thought i wrote what he did down exactly.

```
<div class="main">
<p>Heads or tails? click to toss the coin</p>
<p>IDEA- use this game to decide on comissioning a cute drawing of a cat nose or cat butt!</p>
  <button  onclick="flipCoin()">Flip coin</button>
<p id="responseText"></p>
</body>
</html>
  <script>
  //makes the coin flip! or at least generates a code to simulate it 
 function flipCoin () {
const data = null;

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
//where the magic happens aka the words appear
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
           var responseText = (JSONobject.thistext);
    }
    
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com/headstails",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "XXXXX");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com");

xhr.send(data);
}
    </script>
```

I think that the problem is with the part that says `var responseText = (JSONobject.thistext);`  please help me pass this class

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code is JSONobject defined.

It's likely you're meant to parse the response with JSON.parse.

I'm uncertain of SO's policy with helping schoolwork, so I'll leave it at that.

Note: pay attention to your console output! If you were to run your program, the console would output "Uncaught ReferenceError: JSONobject is not defined"

Comment: More info about [answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

## Placement of the `<script>` tag

The `<script> ... </script>` tags are positioned after the closing `</html>` tag. This means that the script will not be executed, because **it's not part of the page** and therefor won't be executed.

The position of a script matters. If you have a script which selects HTML elements, then it needs to be placed *after* the elements it needs. Generally it's a good idea to place it as low as possible (before the closing `</body>` tag) if this is the case.

```
    <script>
    ...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If needs to execute something before the page is rendered, then placing it in the `<head>` would be a good spot. Your page is executed from top to bottom, keep that in mind.

---

## Parsing JSON

The result of the `XMLHttpRequest` can be found in the `responseText` property. This `responseText` is, like the name suggests, always a form of text, like a string. Your professor probably requested that you turn that string into an object.

Parsing a string to an object can be done with `JSON.parse()`. This function expects a string and returns an object or array if the string has a valid JSON structure.

```
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(JSONObject);
  }
});
```

The value of `JSONObject` should be an object with one property called outcome. The value of that property should be either `"Heads"` or `"Tails"`, like the example below.

```
{
  outcome: "Tails"
}
```

Now because you stored this object in the `JSONObject` you can access it's property by using `JSONObject.outcome` or `JSONObject["outcome"]`. Both syntaxes do the same, but the latter has the ability to use numbers or some non alphabetic characters to access or create a property. However if you know the name, the former (*dot* notation) is easiest to type.

---

## Showing the result

Now to finish it off you just have to show the result of the coin flip request into an element. This is where you have to look at the HTML and check the element you'll want to select. If it has an `id` attribute, then you could use the following line to select that element.

```
var element = document.getElementById("responseText");
```

Now `element` is a reference to the `<p id="responseText"></p>`. So if you want to change, for example, the text of that element, then you could do that by changing the value of the `innerText` or `textContent` property of that element.

```
var text = "Hi";
element.textContent = text;
```

---

From here you'll need to piece these three pieces together. Then you'll script will run. Because it's an homework assignment it's important that you absolutely understand what you're writing down, so please do ask if you have any questions.

Additionally organize your HTML. Making your code more readable makes it easier to find any errors that might encounter.

**Indentation saves lives!**.

Comment: this is what my professor told me but I was so nervous because it was my first zoom call I blanked. thank you so much!!!!! now I don't have to embarrass myself further by not getting it right!

Comment: okay, so I dont understand how its not showing up on my webpage and not just in the console log though. I dont know what im missing.

Comment: Did you place the third part with selecting the element and changing the output inside the  the `readystatechange ` event listener and after the assignment of the `JSONObject` variable?